# Problems with Photorealistic Product Mockups

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, mockup

I think the biggest problem I'm having when using a mock-up template is realistically inserting my product photo into a stock image because it is a glass bottle with clear liquid. Can you guys share any tips on preparing the product photo? Do people normally take several product photos at different angles and focal lengths for different applications?

I'm looking to compare our e-liquid flavors to an actual product to visually describe the flavor. I'm having a hard time keeping my image from looking like a paper cutout.

[image: My attempt]

Another instance I'm having issues is taking a stock photo and inserting my product photo into it and making it look like it was there when the photo was taken. Any tips on doing this? 
[image: Beverage photo]

[image: Root Beer Float photo]

Comment: If you show the exact effect you're looking to produce it would help to narrow down your question. If you have attempted anything so far attach that along with what your process was.

Comment: I just added an image as an example. I need some guidance on making the bottle look like its in the scene

Comment: Not even an attempt of drop shadow/reflection? Also, the focal length difference makes your image look like a paper cutout.

Comment: Hi Trevor. I put your question on hold for a minute because there's simply too much in it right now. Could you break it down maybe into two separate questions. One about making your image look right, and then a second one about whatever this Scene business is (which currently isn't clear anyways). Once edited I'll be happy to reopen for you.

Comment: I will open a second question to ask about making mock ups from scratch. By scene I meant the entire mockup drawing before my product is added. Sorry for being vague there

Comment: Photos with *wildly different* lighting (highlights/shadows) will **always** look out of place. In some instances you may be able to tweak lighting with multiply/screen layers. However, often the key to this is in the *camera* not the computer. Most high end product shots are a *single photo* to ensure lighting is consistent across all products. Ans yes.. multiple photos at different angles with different lighting are taken. Digital files are cheap.. out of 500 shots, maybe 20 will be worthwhile.

Comment: relevant and an attempt at a blanket answer: [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)

Answer (score 1):

To realistically place the Soda Pop Shop dropper into your scene you should replicate the reflection effect of the can.

Starting image

[image: Starting Image]

Using the **Magic Wand Tool** select the background and the can.

[image: Selection]

Invert your selection and **paste in place** twice to get two copies of the dropper bottle.

[image: Paste twice]

Select the lower dropper layer and go to **Edit → Transform → Flip Vertical**

[image: Flip vertically]

Move the top of the flipped layer to the base of the original dropper.

[image: Result]

Add a mask layer to your selection and using the brush tool with your hardness set to 0 hide everything besides the reflected base.

[image: Masked]

Lower the opacity to match that of the can.

[image: Opacity reduction]

Optionally adjust the levels on the dropper to match the highlights and shadows of the can.

[image: Optional levels adjustment]

This will be the final result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Once you've gone to the effort [or even before] of generating a nice drop-shadow, you could have a quick go at trying to match the perspective...

The can image was taken from far closer, with a shorter lens than the bottle.
The 'best' way to fix it would have been at the photography stage [& many other issues with the lighting, not least the mismatch, but also the glare on the metallics could have been handled a lot better]

As this is no longer an option, then you can try to fake it with liquify.
See how much curve the bottom of the can has, compared to the bottle. This is a direct result of the distance discrepancy.

In Filter/Liquify you can attempt to match the two curves...
This was literally one minute's quick attempt. You could do far better with the original source files & some less clumsy manipulation.

[image]

[image]

@TimTroiano's work used as original.

<sup>Colour profile mismatch my fault, but I threw out the working file before I realised.</sup>